# configuring designate in Devstack

Tags: openstack

I am trying to setup designate in Devstack.

I gone through this guide for the same:

- [Designate, a DNSaaS component for OpenStack](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/designate/devstack.html)

But when I am doing stack.sh, I am getting following error:

```
2015-09-28 15:28:09.360 | /opt/devstack/stack.sh:1320:run_phase
2015-09-28 15:28:09.360 | /opt/devstack/functions-common:1593:source
2015-09-28 15:28:09.360 | /opt/devstack/extras.d/85-designate.sh:38:start_designate
2015-09-28 15:28:09.360 | /opt/devstack/lib/designate:340:die
2015-09-28 15:28:09.363 | [ERROR] /opt/devstack/lib/designate:340 Designate did not start
2015-09-28 15:28:10.368 | Error on exit
```

While I was trying to debug, I can be able to track where error was coming from.

In file opt/devstack/lib/designate

```
if ! timeout $SERVICE_TIMEOUT sh -c "while ! wget --no-proxy -q -O- $DESIGNATE_SERVICE_PROTOCOL://$DESIGNATE_SERVICE_HOST:$DESIGNATE_SERVICE_PORT; do sleep 1; done"; then
    die $LINENO "Designate did not start"
fi
```

Please some one help me with fixing the same.

Note: I am using KILO version

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for the same myself.

Actually Issue was with the packages provided by designate.

After executing the stack.sh I have accessed the screen to see the service status.

So that I can be able to see that there was a error as follows:

```
ImportError: No module named oslo_service
```

I have installed the module manually, I can be able to see that It is working fine.

```
pip install oslo.service
```

Now I can be able to see that designate is working fine.